# Need help with apex trigger to retrieve tags

Tags: apex, trigger

Here is what I am trying to do.

We have a custom object Company__c on which users create tags - both public and private. Need to query 3 most recent public tags and update a custom field 'myTalk__c' on Company object. So I decided to create a trigger (my first). Below is what I put so far.

```
trigger updateCompanyTalk on Company__c (after insert, after update) {

    String RecentPublicTags; 

    Map<ID, Company__c> comp = new map<id, Company__c>();

    for(Company__tag  obj :[Select s.Type, s.Name, s.Item.myTalk__c, s.Item.Id, s.ItemId, s.Id From    Company__tag s where s.Item.Id in : trigger.newMap.KeySet()])
    {

        obj.Item.myTags__c = 'Tester Tags';  
        system.debug('Item Type ' + obj.Type); 

        // update obj.values();

    }

}
```

I know there is much more to be added to above code, thought I would get some help. Am I moving in the right direct? Is there any easier way?

Comment: lankan, welcome to Salesforce.StackExchange. There are many resources available with tutorials on how to write triggers. If you visit our help section, you'll discover tips on how to make best use of this site. Posting your code with what you've written to date will likely get a helpful response. Its unclear if you're asking others to help get you started with your trigger, write it for you, or exactly what kind of assistance you actually need.